# Electron doesn't add json file to application

Tags: javascript, json, electron

This is my first electron/node application, I m trying to use a json file  as a datastore. so I created a simple one `index.json` under the app folder next to `index.js|css|html`

I installed a npm package `jsonfile` that is loading just fine

When I try to load my json file the EOF is rised claiming that there is no json file, and I can see that using the DevTools source tab that my json file is not there ( not loaded )

[image]
[image]

I tried force reload from electron app menu.

Here is my files code that is reading my json

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
const file = '/index.json';

var json;

jsonfile.readFile(file)
  .then(obj => json = obj)
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

[image]

------------  Edit

correcting the path name to `index.json` or `./index.json` rises the same issue

Comment: You try to found the file on your root mount point of your HDD. Use `./index.json` instead of `/index.json` or just `index.json`

Comment: You can just use `const json = require("./index.json")` there is no need to use a external librarie or `fs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support

For me the issue was more about file system handling than electron.

All I did is to chmod my project folder to assure that I will be able to read and write into the index.json datastore

`sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/workspaces/electron/myElectronPrpjectFolder`

Then for a better path resolution I used the basic idea used in electron archtype, It more error safe

```
const path = require('path')

const file = path.join(__dirname,'index.json');

var json;
var html = "";// The returned object.


$(document).ready(function () {
    jsonfile.readFile(file)
        .then(obj => {
            json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
            parseIssues(json.children);
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = html;
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))

});
```

You can see that I m using JQuery in this snippet but it also works without JQuery.

in resume, better path resolve policy with granted priveleges on folder.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native `fs` (filesystem) module.

```js
let path = "index.json"
const fs = require('fs');
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path));
```

Comment: Its not necessary. `require()` load json files too. His path to the file is incorrect

Comment: He stated that the path was not involved. Furthermore, he is not requiring a file but a package called jsonfile, I don't know how the package works so I gave an alternative

Comment: My bad, i havent noticed that he use a librarie.